# Specs: What's the purpose of the blank identifier in variable assignment?

Tags: go

I've found this variable declaration [`var _ PropertyLoadSaver = (*Doubler)(nil)`](https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/datastore/datastore_test.go#L334) and I'm wondering what's its purpose. It doesn't seem to initialise anything and as it uses a blank identifier I guess you can't access it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a compile time assertion that `*Doubler` type satisfies the `PropertyLoadSaver` interface. A type implements an interface when the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) for the type is a superset of the method set for the interface.

If the `*Doubler` type does not satisify the interface, then compilation will exit with an error similar to:

```
prog.go:21: cannot use (*Doubler)(nil) (type *Doubler) as type PropertyLoadSaver in assignment:
*Doubler does not implement PropertyLoadSaver (missing Save method)
```

Here's how it works. The code `var _ PropertyLoadSaver` declares an unnamed variable of type `PropertyLoadSaver`. The expression `(*Doubler)(nil)` [converts](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) the untyped nil to a nil value of type `*Doubler`.   The `*Doubler` can only be assigned to the variable of type `PropertyLoadSaver` if `*Doubler` implements the `PropertyLoadSaver` interface.

The blank identifier `_` is used because the variable does not need to be referenced elsewhere in the package. The same result can be achieved with a non-blank identifier:

```
var assertStarDoublerIsPropertyLoadSaver PropertyLoadSaver = (*Doubler)(nil)
```

Comment: Can you provide a ref to the spec? https://golang.org/ref/spec

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat it's not in the spec. It's an unofficial convention.

Comment: @Karrot Kake now I understand how it works. It's a kind of trick. As the blank identifiers are not used in any way I guess it produces no garbage, right?  off-topic:  ``(*Doubler)(nil) `` is nice though. I was not familiar with this either.

Comment: The blank identifier is used because the program does not need to reference the variable.  A non-blank identifier will produce the same amount of garbage as the blank identifier (which is none).