# Golang godoc - Explain group type declarations

Tags: go, data-structures, godoc

There is a piece of GO code I have seen in the GIN library and in the Google docs that look like the following

```
type (
    T0 []string
    T1 []string
    T2 struct{ a, b int }
    T3 struct{ a, c int }
    T4 func(int, float64) *T0
    T5 func(x int, y float64) *[]string
)
```

What I don't understand is, what this grouping is doing and what are some purposes of this implementation (there wasn't much in the docs that went over this topic unless I missed it)

another example from the gin library

```
type (
    RoutesInfo []RouteInfo
    RouteInfo  struct {
        Method  string
        Path    string
        Handler string
    }
        Engine struct {
        RouterGroup
        HTMLRender  render.HTMLRender
        allNoRoute  HandlersChain
        allNoMethod HandlersChain
        noRoute     HandlersChain
        noMethod    HandlersChain
        pool        sync.Pool
        trees       methodTrees

        RedirectTrailingSlash bool


        RedirectFixedPath bool      
        HandleMethodNotAllowed bool
        ForwardedByClientIP    bool
    }
)
```

And lastly - sorry this is different topic but related to this one

```
var _ IRouter = &Engine{}
```

why is there a _ infront of IRouter? I know it's a `blank identifier` but what purpose does it have in that case

Comment: Regarding the first code sample, it's purpose is to demonstrate type declarations to help you understand named and unnamed type declarations. For example, instead of writing `[]string` you can write `T0` or `T1` instead. Interestingly, `T0` and `T1` are considered different because of the names they are given. Recommend reviewing [Type identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity)

Comment: After reading that (which is what I posted in the top part) I don't see an explanation for the anon type. seeing as its `type ()` and the type can encapsulate/group other types + structs what does this do for a data structure and how does it help? take of instance the first two lines of `RoutesInfo []RouteInfo` and `RouteInfo struct {}` why is it inside of the type() instead of having a `var RoutesInfo[] RouteInfo` and another declaration such as `type RouteInfo struct {}` and another line for `type Engine struct {}`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what you're looking at - none of these (besides the last `var _` line that you included) are variable declarations. They're just type declarations. The use of `type ( ... )` is just a shorthand for writing `type` at the beginning of each line separately. It's just a syntax thing - they have the same meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code

```
type (
   A int
   B string
)
```

is functionality identical to

```
type A int
type B string
```

The grouping is just a way to organize code. The grouping is sometimes used to indicate that the types are related in some way.

The use of the blank identifier is explained in [Specs: What's the purpose of the blank identifier in variable assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167403/specs-whats-the-purpose-of-the-blank-identifier-in-variable-assignment).

Answer (score 4):

I think the first part of your question has already been answered. As for the second part, the code

```
var _ IRouter = &Engine{}
```

Creates a compile-time check that `*Engine` implements the `IRouter` interface. We are assigning a value of type `*Engine` to a variable that must be of the type `IRouter`. If a `*Engine` does not satisfy the interface then it won't compile.

This isn't strictly necessary but some people like to put it in where they define a type to ensure it always satisfies an intended interface.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1st question

The statments shown are type declaration
From the Go language spec :
A type declaration binds an identifier, the type name, to a new type that has the same underlying type as an existing type, and operations defined for the existing type are also defined for the new type. The new type is different from the existing type.

> TypeDecl     = "type" ( TypeSpec | "(" { TypeSpec ";" } ")" ) .
>   TypeSpec     = identifier Type .

In layman terms, you can do :

> type

e.g.

```
type Temperature uint8
type WeekTemp [7]Temperature
```

For underlying type, 
 Named instances of the boolean, numeric, and string types are predeclared.
 Composite types are constructed using type literals

> TypeLiteral   = ArrayType | StructType | PointerType | FunctionType | 
>   InterfaceType |
>         SliceType | MapType | ChannelType .

so you can also equivalently do :

```
type (
    Temperature unit8
    WeekTemp [7]Temperature
)
```

another example for composite type

```
type Tree struct {
    leftChild, rightChild *Tree
}
```

For 2nd question,

Edited :
I wasn't aware of this but trying on go playground , it looks like the answer from  jcbwlkr is indeed right.

So trying to compile

```
type MyInterface interface{
    someMethod() 
}
type MyType struct{}
var _ MyInterface = &MyType{}
```

will give this error

> cannot use MyType literal (type *MyType) as type MyInterface in
>   assignment:   *MyType does not implement MyInterface (missing
>   someMethod method)

So it indeed does a compile time check to make sure that Engine struct conforms to IRouter interface. neat