# what does blank do for interface?

Tags: go

Trying to understand the blank functionality of `interface` in go.

```
type Manager interface {
    GetAge(name string) (int, error)
}

type manager struct {
}

var _ Manager = &manager{}

func NewManager() Manager {
    return &manager{}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167403/specs-whats-the-purpose-of-the-blank-identifier-in-variable-assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a particular idiom used to assert at compile time whether a concrete type implements a given interface.

In the above code, if the person writing the `manager` type forgets to implement a `GetAge` method for it, the code won't compile, and the compilation error will tell them exactly which methods are missing.

It may appear a bit redundant here, but if the interface required to be implemented by a type has a large number of methods, this technique may be helpful.

Note that because of the above reasons, the code above won't compile. Also, you need to make sure, give that `&manager{}` is used in the blank declaration, that it's `*manager` (pointer to `manager`) that implements the `Manager` interface, and not simply `manager`.